# spring-security logging level debug inconsistent behavior

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security, log4j, slf4j

What is the correct way to set `logging level == debug` for Spring Security 4.x? I'm using `slf4j/log4j`.

Here is what I tried, log4j.properties:

```
...
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Also tried with:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

The following returns false in     `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication`:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: "
                + authResult);
    }
```

However in `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` the test for debug returns true   and I can see debug output:

```
if (debug) {
    logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed");
}
```

The console is filled with statements such as the following, indicating that logging level is indeed `debug`:

```
2016-01-20 12:10:34,849 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest.propertyEquals(321):  - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2016-01-20 12:10:34,849 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest.propertyEquals(321):  - queryString: both null (property equals)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use a custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, maybe a customized `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`? If this is true, then I think I can explain the behaviour.

It is that the logger `logger` used in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (as well as in every subclass of `GenericFilterBean`) is provided by the potected final `logger` field of `GenericFilterBean`. It is initialized by this code:

```
/** Logger available to subclasses */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

as you can see, the logger name is "defined" by `Object.getClass()`. Therefore the every `logger.debug(...)` statement in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is published by the logger of the concrete subclass!

So when you have a customized AuthenticationProcessingFilter (that is likely no resisting in the `org.springframework.security` package), the you need to configure the logging framework to print the debug statements for this class/package too!